# Is there a way to use a tmLanguage grammar to extend vscode integrated markdown extensions syntax highlighting?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, vscode-extensions, tmlanguage, markdown-it

I am working on a language extension for vscode. I defined a tmLanguage file and everything works nicely. In the hover feature, using `vscode.MarkdownString.appendCodeblock()` the markdown is being interpreted correctly and syntax highlighting for my custom language just works out of the box, by doing something like:

```
const content = new MarkdownString("", true)
content.appendMarkdown("## Examples: \n")
content.appendCodeblock(examples, "lmps")
```

where `examples` contains some example code in my custom language and `"lmps"` is my language identifier.
([Example Image Hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifVV6.png))

I wonder if there is a way to achieve the same thing in a webview. I succeeded displaying the `content` in a webview, compiling the markdownString into html:

```
async function set_doc_panel_content(panel: DocPanel | undefined, md_content: vscode.MarkdownString) {
        const html: string = await vscode.commands.executeCommand('markdown.api.render', md_content.value) as string;
        panel!.webview.html = html;
    }
```

So far so good, but in this way, markdown doesn't know my custom language and doesn't do any syntax highlighting. ([Example image Webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzhgY.png)) Now, I understand that adding language-support to the Markdown extension can be achieved by contributing a markdown-it plugin by returning an object in the activation function.

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

...

    return {
        extendMarkdownIt(md: any) {
          return md.use(require('markdown-it-emoji'));
        }
}
```

However, this requires actually developing a dedicated markdown-it plugin if I see that right. I wonder if there is an easier way to integrate my language into the markdown api. Since vscode can obviously do it natively in hover and completion suggestions already. Can I somehow use this functionality in a webview maybe? Alternatively, is there a way to generate a markdown-it plugin from a tmLanguage-file without having to learn markdown-it plugin development in depth? Perhaps someone has pointers to projects where something like this was done?

Comment: https://github.com/mjbvz/vscode-fenced-code-block-grammar-injection-example may help

Comment: @Gama11 I had found that too and I already implemented that. As I see this only enables the highlighting when working on markdown file (that works), but it doesn't actually translate the highlighting into the Preview, unless I am missing something...

Comment: Edit: Here is an example of what I mean in the above comment: https://i.postimg.cc/h4XG97fj/Screenshot-at-2020-06-11-19-24-20.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem:
There doesn't seem to be a super-easy way. The easiest-to-use package I've found for the job is [highlights](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highlights). However, this package (and others like first-mate) depend on the native module [Oniguruma](https://github.com/atom/node-oniguruma). That package needs to be compiled against the specific version of Electron. That makes it very difficult to publish a vscode extension to the marketplace, because vscode doesn't allow to run this compilation in the package installation.

A solution I've found is to provide a highlight function to markdown-it.
The grammar as .plist or .tmLanguage can be read by [vscode-textmate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vscode-textmate) for example. This package can be used with [vscode-oniguruma](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-oniguruma). The trick here is to load WASM in order for it to work:

```js
const oniguruma = require('vscode-oniguruma')
const oniguruma_root: string = path.join(env.appRoot, 'node_modules.asar', 'vscode-oniguruma')
const wasm = readFileSync(path.join(oniguruma_root, 'release', 'onig.wasm')).buffer;
const on_wasm = oniguruma.loadWASM(wasm);
```

Then one can do:

```js
const registry = new vsctm.Registry({
    onigLib: Promise.resolve({
        createOnigScanner: (sources) => new oniguruma.OnigScanner(sources),
                createOnigString: (str) => new oniguruma.OnigString(str)
            }),
            loadGrammar: () => {
                return readJSON2plist(path.join(context.extensionPath, 'syntaxes', 'lmps.tmLanguage.json'))
            .then(data => {
                return vsctm.parseRawGrammar(data)
            }).catch(null)
    }
});
    
const grammar = await registry.loadGrammar('source.lmps')
    
const md = require('markdown-it')(
    {
        html: true,
        linkify: true,
        typographer: true,
        langPrefix: '',
        highlight: function (str: string, lang: string) {
            if (grammar && lang && lang == 'lmps') {
                return tokenize_lmps(str, grammar)
            }
        }
    });
return md
```

`md` can then be used to render markdown content:

```js
let html = md.render(md_string)
```

A working implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/ThFriedrich/lammps_vscode/blob/master/src/highlight_fcns.ts)